# Check if "Sync Passwords" is enabled in Windows 10

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10, uwp

Windows 10 (and 8.1/possibly 8) let a user sync passwords via their Microsoft Account. I'd like to leverage this to sync some secure data via the PasswordVault class.

Is there any way to programmatically check if the user has Password syncing enabled? I'd like to be able to inform the user that syncing won't work if it's not enabled.

Comment: May I ask where a user can manually disable this?

Comment: In Windows 10: Settings -> Accounts -> Sync your settings -> Passwords

Comment: Can't remember in Win 8.1, but it's something similar. Additionally, they don't sync at all if the device isn't trusted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, at least for now, is that you can't - I asked Andy Wigley (MSFT technical evangelist) and he said:

"No way of discovering that I'm afraid."

( https://twitter.com/andy_wigley/status/656916864384286720 )